# How to make $scope value in another controller update when calling function inside factory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having 2 controller placed on a same page and using a same factory. All things i want is when a function in controller 1 execute, it will call to the function inside factory then the $scope in controller 2 will be update its value. When page is loaded controller can get the list but after controller 1 call the factory, nothing was changed, no any call to server...

Here is Controller 1:

```
app.controller('controller1', function ($scope, $http, globalServices) {
  $scope.createFuntion = function(){
    $http.post(url, $.param(some_object)).then(function(response){
        //Handle something ...
        globalServices.userList();
    });
  }});
```

Here is Controller 2:

```
app.controller('controller2', function ($scope, $http, globalServices) {
$scope.users = globleServices.userList();});
```

Here is factory:

```
app.factory('globalServices', function ($http) {
return{
    userList: function(){
        var users_data = [];
        $http.get(url).then(function (response) {
            var res = response.data;
            if (res.status === 200) {
                angular.forEach(res.data, function (staff) {
                    users_data.push(staff);
                });
            } else {
                alert('Oops! Somethings went wrong!');
            }
        });
        return users_data;
    }
}});
```

Comment: I think you could use [event $broadcast](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$broadcast)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an object in your factory that will somehow serve as a state then create a getter for it. Separate your fetch function and getUserList. See the modified code below.

```
app.factory('globalServices', function ($http) {
  var list = {
     users_data: []
  }

  return{
    getUserList: getUserList,
    fetchUserList: fetchUserList
  }

  function getUserList() {
    return list;
  }

  function fetchUserList() {
        list.users_data = [];
        $http.get(url).then(function (response) {
            var res = response.data;
            if (res.status === 200) {
                angular.forEach(res.data, function (staff) {
                    list.users_data.push(staff);
                });
            } else {
                alert('Oops! Somethings went wrong!');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Now in your controller1

```
app.controller('controller1', function ($scope, $http, globalServices) {
  $scope.createFuntion = function(){
    $http.post(url, $.param(some_object)).then(function(response){
        //Handle something ...
        globalServices.fetchUserList();
    });
  }});
```

and in your controller2

```
app.controller('controller2', function ($scope, $http, globalServices) {
   $scope.users = globalServices.getUserList();
});
```

Now your `$scope.users` listen to every change in your `user_data`.
Access the array thru `$scope.users.users_data`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i tried with your code but i got the error that globalServices.getUserList() is not a function and inside fetchUserList() have some error at line this.list.users_data = [];

Comment: I got some variable mismatch inside `fetchUserList()` and I removed the `this` as well cause I think it is the one causing the error. Please try the modified code.

Comment: It's alway tell me fetchUserList() and getUserList() is not a function...:<

Comment: did you copy my whole factory again? I did lots of modifications on it. Try copying it as a whole.

Comment: No i did not. I just fix in my code, i removed "this" inside fetchUserList() and getUserList(). but error still occur

Comment: please copy the codes I've posted. I modified lots aside from removing the `this` :)

Comment: Ahh, my careless, i did not remove () inside return object of the factory :D

Comment: I also changed the object array to `users_data` because it had a mismatch earlier. I used `user_data` earlier.

Comment: We cannot using an array users_data instead of put it into a list object??? The fectUserList() and getUserList() has run, but have i do something like $apply scope to make it refresh the ng-repeat  in table??

Comment: This is what @Adrian explained above. We need to put your users_data inside an object so that we can track it. If we don't put it inside an object, the app wont know that there's new data because it only assigns a reference to it. Anyway, did my code work now?

Comment: can i use a variable for store the array of fetchUserList()? i means ````var tmp = globalServices.fetchUserList();```` then ````$scope.users = tmp.user_data```` . I tried to use this but the ````$scope.users```` might not be changed...

Comment: Are you trying to achieve something else? This `$scope.users = globalServices.getUserList();` already listens to whatever changes to `users_data`. There's not need to reassign it to `$scope.users` over and over again. And `fetchUserList()` only fetches data and pushes it to `users_data`, it doesn't return anything to its caller.

Comment: ah, b'cause i want to ````$scope.users```` will get the property ````users_data```` from ````fetchUserList()```` so when i use ````ng-repeat````, i've to only call ````users```` instead of ````users.users.data````

Answer (score 2):

There is a thing in the AngularJs space and JavaScript in general referred to as the dot rule. If you have a property on an object like

```
service.data
```

when you assign that to another object

```
$scope.data = service.data;
```

It assigns a reference to the object and now if you update the service the controller does not know about the new data.

Using the dot rule you can have an object on the service that holds data objects

```
service.data = {};
```

this object should never change reference to a new object and always be the same instance and you can add new properties to it

```
service.data.userList = response.userList;
```

Now if you assign the data in the service to the scope

```
$scope.data = service.data;
```

and in the template use

```
<div ng-repeat="user in data.userList">{{ user.name }}</div>
```

Userlist will be updated when the service updates the userList.

You should never inject $http into controllers, you should only inject services into controllers and have services make http calls. Injecting $scope is an outdated method of doing AngularJs, you are following outdated tutorials and should look into using the controllerAs syntax or use components that wrap the controllerAs syntax with an Angular 2 style of development.

Comment: 2 controller is not-related together, so when execute create or update function in controller 1 i want to reload the user list in controller 2 with newest data from server...

Comment: And because both controllers are pointing to the same instance of the data object then the other controller will have the same userList

Comment: @StevenDang this is just a more detailed explanation of what I did in my answer. This is just basically what I did.